# In need of Atharva Veda books translated by Dr Tulsi Ram

Tags: vedas, resource, atharva-veda

I have vol 1 of Atharva veda by tulsi ram.May I have the link to the rest of the volumes?[image]

Comment: How many more volumes are there?

Comment: I don't know.But in the 1st volume there are 10 mandalas.the rest of total 20 mandalas are not there

Comment: But Atharva Veda is divided into 20 Kandas ..then why are you saying Mandalas?

Comment: Btw did you buy the book or it is available for free download somewhere?

Comment: Oh.I meant kandas It was a mistake.I collected it from a friend.

Comment: Ok thanks, that means you already have half of it.. there must be one more volume

Comment: Do u have the rest of the volumes by Tulsi ram?

Comment: No I don't have :) ..In fact I heard about the book for the first time from your post

Comment: Dr tulsi rama's translation is the best. Griffith,muller etc have adulterated the translation of vedas

Comment: Ok fine ..let's hope you get the remaining volumes

Answer (score 1):

This is the link of complete Atharva Veda in English translated by Tulsi Ram with detailed commentary. Dr Tulsi Ram's translation is the best. By the way, the filename is in Bengali, but the book is in English! So do not get confused. All 20 kandas are there divided into two volumes. In the middle of the book the second volume starts (11 - 20 Kandas).

https://archive.org/details/susmitaroychowdhury512_gmail_20180202

To get the English translation of all 4 Vedas by Dr Tulsi Ram, please go to the following link provided by the same person. Thanks to her.

https://archive.org/details/susmitaroychowdhury512_gmail

These pdf files have an annoying yellow background colour. However, with any pdf editor (like PDF X change editor) you can easily remove all background colour and can get pure white background! Otherwise, file qualities are excellent. Files are small, no watermark and not secured so you can annotate easily!

Comment: Yes! Of course. That's why I could read the filename.